# Add Html element in div vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have been searching for 4 hours , cant even get my head to understand what to use
basically i want to add a new row (article tag) to a div element , everytime the user press the addbutton
in my method how can i pass this HTMLto the div :

```
<article class="col-md-11 col-md-offset-1 card" custom_attrib=atrrib_value> <span>
{{NEW VALUE}} - {{NEW VALUE_2}}
</span>
<span >
<button class="btn btn-theme btn-default btn-xs pull-left" @click="deleteItem" ><i class="fa fa-times inline"></i></button>
</span>
</article>
```

I have to say i need to put some custom attrib on the Article tag each time thats why i want to make a new tag on each request
if we take a look at this https://codepen.io/Pizzi/pen/GMOQXy
when pressing the + (add) a row drops , i want to do the same thing but the important part is the new row with article tag needs new custom_attrib and value everytime

another jsfiddle example : https://jsfiddle.net/50wL7mdz/17736/
instead of those input box will be my article with custom attrib and value

Comment: Are you saying that each time the actual name 'custom_attrib`  of the attribute will be different? Or just the value?

Comment: the value will be different not the attrib itself

Comment: So the trouble you are facing is if you update the attrib it changes the previous ones right? And do the old rows ever need to get updated?  Or once they are created the content will stay the same?

Comment: trouble im having is i dont know how to actually append the html to my div in general

Comment: Ok I believe I understand now.

Comment: You don't have to append HTML to the DOM manually, just use Vue's list rendering (data-driven approach):  https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Mapping-an-Array-to-Elements-with-v-for

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You make an array. When the user clicks "add new" you will append a new item to the array which contains HTML with two input fields. When you append it, Vuejs will re-render the HTML with the changed data.

```js
// Vue.js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
   items:[],
   item:['NEW VALUE','NEW VALUE_2'],
   
  },
  created(){
   this.items.push(this.item);
  },
  methods: 
  {
    add()
    {
      this.item = ['</br><input type="text"/>','<input type="text"/></br>'];
      this.items.push(this.item);
    }
  }
  
})
```

```html
<h2>Vue.js</h2>

<div id="app">

<article class="col-md-11 col-md-offset-1 card" custom_attrib=atrrib_value> 
<span v-for="item in items" ><span v-html="item[0]"></span> - <span v-html="item[1]"></span></span>
<span >
<button v-on:click="add" class="btn btn-theme btn-default btn-xs pull-left">
+
</button>
</span>
</article>

</div>

<!-- Vue.js -->
<script src="https://vuejs.org/js/vue.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Highly appreciate it my friend ,the article itself contains css so can we put the v-for on the article itself ?

Comment: <div id="app">

<article v-for="item in items" class="col-md-11 col-md-offset-1 card" custom_attrib=atrrib_value> 
<span><span v-html="item[0]"></span> - <span v-html="item[1]"></span></span>
<span >
<br/>

</span>
</article>
<button v-on:click="add" class="btn btn-theme btn-default btn-xs pull-left" @click="deleteItem" >
<i class="fa fa-times inline"></i>
Add new
</button>
</div>

Comment: you can make it like that

Comment: thanks dude, now im getting  vue.js?3de6:1743 TypeError: Cannot read property '_withTask' of undefined , can u help me on that too ? that would be awsome

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52425393/cannot-read-property-withtask-of-undefined-vuejs   again thanks for this