# Vuejs - Cannot read property '_withTask' of undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to add new html to my div after pressing a button, using `v-for`.
But after I press the button I get this error and the element (article) gets added to the div once but after that it won't work anymore.

> vue.js?3de6:1743 TypeError: Cannot read property '_withTask' of undefined
>       at remove$2 (eval at  (app.js:561), :7078:13)
>       at updateListeners (eval at  (app.js:561), :2067:7)
>       at Array.updateDOMListeners (eval at  (app.js:561),:7091:3)
>       at patchVnode (eval at  (app.js:561), :5918:62)
>       at updateChildren (eval at  (app.js:561), :5809:9)
>       at patchVnode (eval at  (app.js:561), :5923:29)
>       at updateChildren (eval at  (app.js:561), :5809:9)
>       at patchVnode (eval at  (app.js:561), :5923:29)
>       at updateChildren (eval at  (app.js:561), :5809:9)
>       at patchVnode (eval at  (app.js:561), :5923:29)

HTML CODE :

```
<article v-for="item in range">
    <span>
        {{item[0]}} - {{item[1]}}
    </span>
    <span>
        <button  class="btn btn-theme btn-default btn-xs pull-left"  @click="deleteItem" ><i class="fa fa-times inline"></i></button>
    </span>
</article>
```

JS :

```
data() {
    return {
        majornew:this.major,
        certificate:this.cert,
        range:[], 
        item:[],
    };
},

methods: {
    addmajorcert(majortext,certext) {
        this.item = [majortext,certext];
        this.range.push(this.item);
        console.log(majortext,certext);
    },
},
```

**Updated :There are two select boxes where values get sent**

```
<v-select v-model="selectedmajor" label="major_text" id="major" name="majornew" :options="majornew" >
</v-select> 
<v-select v-model="selectedcert" :options="certificate" label="lc_text" id="cert" v-on:click="certificate"></v-select> 

<button v-on:click="addmajorcert(selectedmajor,selectedcert)">
    +
</button>
```

The select box returns an object like :

```
{ "major_id": 2, "major_text": "industrial", "number_of_used": 1 }
```

When I do  a `console.log` I can see the values being passed.

Comment: Where's the add button?

Comment: range its an empty array at the beginning till we push an array into it and after i push the array i get the error

Comment: the options are strings , and its an object not an array , how can i setup a runnable example with vue when im stuck :(

Comment: Well if I make an example for what you describe, I do not have the error. So obviously the error must be in a part of the code you do not show: https://jsfiddle.net/Sirence/w6fb1v2c/3/ Your first step should be to set up a small example yourself where the error is visible with your data, so others can try and help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is my try,

[image: code in link]

[image: code in photo]

Tell me if there is something that you do not understand or if I miss something.

Comment: thanks to you and Sirence js , i figured out what i was doing wrong , what was worst was after fixing it i still had the same error than i found out i had some on click methods which were not defined in methods , they were causing the error too. again thanks to both of u

Answer (score 6):

I had same problem and that was because i am using an event but it was not defined in script here is example problem :

```
<template>
 <div>
  <button @click="deleteItem"></button>
 </div>
</template>
```

So you can see i am using `deleteItem` method but in scripts below methods object i have no function with that name. and that causing me error _withTask. I think this can someone else.

```
<script>
 export default {
  methods: {
   // No function with name deleteItem
  }
 }
</script>
```

Basically the error is caused when an event function's is undefined in simple language :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<article v-for="item in range">
```

You have both range and item defined in your data, yet you loop over range and name each iteration item.
Not sure but it could be problematic, try to change the name of your item in your v-for :

```
<article v-for="majorcert in range">
```

By the way I think you need a v-key when using v-for, it could be :

```
<article v-for="majorcert in range" :key="majorcert.major_id">
```